# Hide page parameters in Flutter web app URL

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have a page names example.com/items that contains list of items. I click on one item and it goes to example.com/[clicked_item_name] that contains name of the item. I pass "name" parameter for the page containing item name and URL shows as example.com/[clicked_item_name]?name=[name_parameter]. Is it possible to remove the parameter part to show only example.com/[clicked_item_name] in URL. My purpose is use same URL for item detail pages whose URL does not change when item name is updated (For SEO purposes for each item)

I researched URL redirection but redirection approach is my not first preference. My preference is generate static URL for each item.

```
queryParams: {
        'name': serializeParam(
            listViewPlacesRecord.name,
            ParamType.String,
        ),
        'type': serializeParam(
            listViewPlacesRecord.type,
            ParamType.String,
        ),
        'rating': serializeParam(
            listViewPlacesRecord.rating,
            ParamType.double,
        ),...
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but what package are you using? Can you include your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ValentinVignal I use no code builder flutterflow to build the app but as I know it uses go_router package.